How can i avoid circular dependency in nestjs
For example when i create CRUD of blog
Usecase : Delete Article
When i delete article, need to remove comment.
But when create comment, need to validation article
// article-comment.service.ts
async createComment(articleId: string, comment: string) {
  const article = articleService.get(articleId)
  if (!article) throw new SomeException()

  // ... create comment
}

async remove(articleId) {
 
}

// article.service.ts
async deleteArticle(articleid: string) {
  // ... validation

  commentService.remove(articleId)
}

async get(articleId: string)  {
  return repository.find(articleId)
}

articleService and commentService have circular dependency, How can i avoid it?
I don't want to use ForwardRef..
Someone says, use EventEmitter and Use SharedModule? But What's the best way i didn't know..
Please give me advice, Thank you
Nestjs, Architecture

I guess you could inject repositories instead of services. It would certainly help you with business rules validations and avoid coupling and therefore referencing.
Something like
// article-comment.service.ts
async createComment(articleId: string, comment: string) {
  const article = this.articleRepository.get(articleId)

  if (!article) throw new SomeException()

  // ... create comment
}

// article.service.ts
async deleteArticle(articleid: string) {
  // ... validation

  this.commentRepository.remove(articleId)
}

If you're using an ORM like Typeorm you can also take a look at cascade.

If exists a large number of dependencies between services, you can create problematic methods in utilities (in our case, article-comment.util.ts and article.util.ts).
These methods additionally pass the connection as an argument (in the case of TypeORM: DataSource, EntityManager or Repository). You can call methods in utilities from any service and there will be no cyclic links.
Something like
// article-comment.service.ts
import {getArticle} from "article.util"
import {removeComment} from "article-comment.util"
async createComment(articleId: string, comment: string) {
  const article = await getArticle(dataSource, articleId); // OLD: articleService.get(articleId)
  if (!article) throw new SomeException()
  // ... create comment
}
async remove(articleId) {
  await removeComment(dataSource, articleId);
}

// article-comment.util.ts
export const removeComment = async (dataSource: DataSource, articleId: string):Promise<Boolean> => { }

// article.service.ts
import {getArticle} from "article.util.ts"
import {removeComment} from "article-comment.util"
async deleteArticle(articleid: string) {
  // ... validation
  await removeComment(dataSource, articleId)
}
async get(articleId: string)  {
  return getArticle(dataSource, articleId)
}

// article.util.ts
export const getArticle = async (dataSource: DataSource, articleId: string):Promise<ArticleEntity> => dataSource.manager.find(ArticleEntity, articleId);

